# Photons from resonant biexciton excitation as basis for entanglement

Tags: photons, semiconductor-physics, laser

I'm currently reading [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms5251) on generating time-bin entanglement from the photons emitted by a quantum dot (QD). The process described uses a resonant excitation of a biexciton state of said quantum dot.

The resonant laser pump pulse can transfer the phase of the pump pulses (that are generated by a interferometer before exciting the QD) and thus the coherence created by the pump interferometer to the biexciton state.

The problem I have with understanding is the following: the excitation by the laser must occur to the biexciton state $| b \rangle$. This happens through a virtual level (see image). [image: Horizontal polarized laser excites QD.]

But, for this to happen it looks like 2 photons are stacked on top of each other. Can someone explain the process that allows this? So far when I heard about resonant excitation, it was always with single photons matching the "energy gap" between state 1 and state 2.

**Addendum:** so, while typing my question, I came across a passage in my book on quantum optics that mentions "two-photon absorption" from the ground state. I guess the question thus boils down to: **how does two-photon absorption work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excitation of the quantum dot happens through two-photon absorption (TPA), a process in which two photons are absorbed simultaneously leading to the creation of a bi-exciton. Since TPA requires two photons to be at the same location (of the quantum dot), its probability is proportional to the *squared* intensity of the excitation light (rather than linear dependence as in the case of conventional resonant excitation) and thus is a nonlinear optical process. For the same reason, TPA is a much weaker process than conventional (single-photon) absorption and requires a larger excitation intensity.